# Slot Machine Simulation with Python 3 functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to return multiple values from a python function?
Bellow is a Python 3 code to simulate a slot machine with using functions get_slot_results() and the function must return three values.
In python 3 it says the user defined functions can not return more than one value so I had this issue in get_slot_results() function bellow.
I found a hint of a workaround by using either a list or a tuple but not sure how to do that in the program body

```
import random

def play_again():
    
    while True:
        pa = input("Do you want to play again? ==> ")
        if pa == 'y' or pa == 'Y' or pa == 'yes' or pa == 'YES':
            return True
            break
        elif pa == 'n' or pa == 'N' or pa == 'no' or pa == 'NO':
            return False
            break
        else:
            print("You must enter Y/YES/N/NO to continue. Please try again")
            pass
        
        
     
def get_wager(bank : int):
    while True:
        b = int(input("How many chips do you want to wager? ==> "))
        if b <= 0:
            print("Too low a value, you can only choose 1 -", bank, "chips")
        elif b > bank:
            print("Too high a value, you can only choose 1 -", bank, "chips")
        elif b > 0 and b <= bank:
            break            
    return b

def get_slot_results():
    r1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    return r1, r2, r3

def get_matches(ra, rb, rc) -> int:
    if ra == rb and ra == rc:
        return 3
    elif ra == rb or ra == rc or rb == rc:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

def get_bank():
    while True:
        bn = int(input("How many chips do you want to start with? ==>"))
        if bn <= 0:
            print("Too low a value, you can only choose 1 - 100 chips")
        elif bn > 100:
            print("Too high a value, you can only choose 1 - 100 chips")
        elif bn > 0 and bn <= 100:
            return bn
            break

def get_payout(wager, matches):
    if matches == 3:
        pay1 = (10 * wager) - wager
    elif matches == 2:
        pay1 = (3 * wager) - wager
    elif matches == 0:
        pay1 = - wager
    return pay1    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    playing = True
    wager = 0
    while playing:
        bank = get_bank()
        while bank >= wager:
            wager = get_wager(bank)
            get_slot_results()  #**Here I need to get the three values** 
            matches = get_matches(reel1, reel2, reel3)
            payout = get_payout(wager, matches)
            bank = bank + payout

            print("Your spin", reel1, reel2, reel3)
            print("You matched", matches, "reels")
            print("You won/lost", payout)
            print("Current bank", bank)
            print()
           
        print("You lost all", 0, "in", 0, "spins")
        print("The most chips you had was", 0)
        playing = play_again()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/), like so:

```
reel1, reel2, reel3 = get_slot_results()
```

Comment: Also, next time please give a [mre]

Comment: Did not work, I am getting this error:   TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @Sarahalsharifi are you sure you have the parentheses at the end?

Comment: I actually copied your answer. I will restart the Visual Studio Code and my computer because it was acting weird. I will update here shortly if it works. Thanks anyways